# Ruby: How can I write a digest to a file in binary format

Tags: ruby, binary-data, digest, bigint

I need to store a Digest::SHA512 object to a file in **binary** format.
That seemed trivial, but whatever I try just write it as an hexadecimal string.
I was expecting the following code to work:

```
bindigest=digest.update(chall)
File.open('sha1.bin', 'wb') {|file| file.write(bindigest) }
```

but it does not: it convert to plain text.
A similar question seems unanswered:
[Can I serialize a ruby Digest::SHA1 instance object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9883649/can-i-serialize-a-ruby-digestsha1-instance-object)

Using unpack tools require translating a bigint into a binary string, which again is not trivial...
Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`to_s` method](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest/Instance.html#method-i-to_s) of `Digest` returns the hexadecimal encoding of the hash, so this is what you get by default when trying to output it (since Ruby will use `to_s` when writing). To get the raw binary, use [`digest`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest/Instance.html#method-i-digest):

```
digest = Digest::SHA512.new
digest.update(chall)
File.open('sha1.bin', 'wb') { |file| file.write(digest.digest) }
```

Alternatively you could use the [class method version of `digest`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/digest/rdoc/Digest/Class.html#method-c-digest) if you’re not calculating the hash in chunks:

```
digest = Digest::SHA512.digest(chall)
File.open('sha1.bin', 'wb') { |file| file.write(digest) }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, tank you Matt!!